# How can i resize a tooltip on moseover() using ActionScript and add more interactive content in it?

Tags: actionscript, resize, tooltip

I like to make a general module in ActionScript to create an interactive tooltip. The tooltip has to resize on mouseover() event and then should contain hyperlinks once resized. Thanks

Comment: how do you want this to work exactly? Tooltips are usually shown when you mouse over a component, and disappear, if the mouse moves out of this component - for example into the tooltip.

Comment: I need the tooltip to stay there. And it should also contain hyperlinks. When the user clicks the hyperlink in the tooltip, then user should be directed to another webpage. Is this possible in Actionscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Are you using Flex? or just pure Actionscript? In the case of actionscript:

Add an event listener to rollOver event, and display the tooltip, heres some code:

[in some function, after the comp is added to the stage ]

```
public function myComp(){
     myComponent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,createToolTip);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,destroyToolTip);
}

private var toolTip:CustomToolTip;

private function createToolTip(e:MouseEvent):void{
     toolTip = new CustomToolTip();
     stage.addChild(myToolTip);
     myToolTip.x = e.localX;
     myToolTip.y = e.localY;   
}

private function destroyToolTip(e:Event):void{
    stage.removeChild(toolTip);
    toolTip = null;
}
```

(you might need to refine the tooltip destruction logic, now it gets destroyed, if you click anywhere. For example you could call Event.stopPropagation, if the user click inside the tooltip. )
The custom tooltip class:

```
package{
class CustomToolTip extends Sprite{
    public function CustomToolTip():void{
        super();
        // put drawing logic, children, text,... here.
    }
}
}
```